# Why does the second catch block get omitted? (Java SE 8 OCA - Exceptions)

Tags: java, exception

So I was trying to solve this sample question for the OCA Java SE 8 exam, but I got it wrong.

```
public static void main(String... a) {
    System.out.print("a");
    try {
        System.out.print("b");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("1");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("c");
        throw new RuntimeException("1");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("d");
        throw new RuntimeException("2");
    } finally {
        System.out.print("e");
        throw new RuntimeException("3");
    }
}
```

[Here is the image of the try-catch sequence in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzLbv.png)

I believe the answer should be:

```
abcdeException in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 3
```

but the answer is actually:

```
abceException in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 3
```

My thought process is that first, the main method prints "a", then prints "b". Then, an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown, and caught in the first catch block. Then, inside the first catch block, "c" is printed, and a `RuntimeException` is thrown. I really do believe, then, that the second catch block catches the `RuntimeException` and prints "d", while throwing another `RuntimeException`, where the thread then "floats" over to the finally block, printing "e" and then throwing the `RuntimeException("3")` instead. I really can't see why the second catch block is simply ignored.

Therefore, `abcdeException in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 3` should be printed in my opinion.

Am I missing anything in terms of reasoning? How should my sequence of thoughts be instead?

Comment: Please provide code as a text in question. Don't add images of code

Comment: As for the question, there is only one try block in that code and it throws `IllegalArgumentException` so it is catched in the first catch block. The exception thrown in that catch will not be catched as it is not inside a try block. It will then execute the finally statement.

Comment: Bad formatting makes it look like you are catching inside the existing catch block, but you arent. A catch only catches if there is an error inside the try block. If you were to have a try-catch inside the catch block thats a different story

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple `catch` blocks of one `try` block do not "chain catch" or "recatch" any exceptions that might be thrown inside a `catch` block. The `catch` blocks only "observe" the content of the `try` block they belong to. So when your code

```
try {
    System.out.print("b");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("1");
}
```

throws the `IllegalArgumentException` then the first applicable `catch` block is executed, as defined in the [Java Language Specification 14.20. The try statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20):

> If a value is thrown and the `try` statement has one or more `catch` clauses that can catch it, then control will be transferred to the first such `catch` clause.

In your case, you have the applicable catch blocks

```
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("c");
    throw new RuntimeException("1");
}
```

and

```
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    System.out.println("d");
    throw new RuntimeException("2");
}
```

and from these two blocks, (only) the first one is called (the one for `IllegalArgumentException`). The other `catch` block is not called, so you don't get the output `d` from it. Nothing in the JLS says that **all** possible `catch` block will be executed, only the **first** one will.

Keep in mind that `try-catch` blocks are not `switch` blocks where you can have `case:` blocks without a `break;` statement (and the execution will "fall through").

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you for clarifying! Though this may have been a no-brainer for some, I was unable to find any source to clarify, including my study guide for my Java SE 8 Certification.